# How do you get a custom Gnu screen config to load .bash_profile and .bash_aliases?

Tags: gnu-screen

I have a custom screen configuration `myscreenconfig` and a `.screenrc`. `myscreenconfig` looks like this:

```
source .screenrc
screen 0 bash
title 'notes' 
screen 1 bash
title 'bash' 
[etc.]
```

`.screenrc` has these lines at the top:

```
altscreen on
shell -${SHELL}
```

My `.bash_profile` file sets a lot of things and then calls `source $HOME/.bash_aliases`.

If I start `screen` without any arguments, my `.bash_profile` gets loaded and `.bash_aliases` gets loaded. But if I start screen via `screen -c myscreenconfig`, only `.bash_profile` gets loaded, and not `.bash_aliases`. Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: Though answered, this really should be on serverfault...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not using login shells in `myscreenconfig`. Use (IIRC) `screen 0 -bash`, or try combinations with `deflogin on`.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was making a symbolic link between wherever I had my bash settings and .bashrc (which I did not have):

```
ln -s ~/.bash_profile ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on one of the machines I use. After reading the suggestion above about linking the two bash resource files, I realized that the following section had been put in comment in the .bash_profile file on this particular machine:

```
# Get the aliases and functions
# if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
#    . ~/.bashrc
# fi
```

After removing the comment signs (#) from before the `if` block lines, settings in `.bashrc` became available in screen sessions as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm use this in my .bashrc

```
if [ "$TERM" = "screen" ]; then
        if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then
                . ~/.bash_profile
        fi
fi
```